# How can I test XForms using submissions if I don't have the services available?

Tags: testing, service, echo, orbeon, xforms

I want to test XForms that performs submissions, but in my environment I don't have access to the services the submissions will ultimately call, either because they haven't be developed yet, or are behind a firewall. With some XForms implementations I can get around this by using a `file:///` URLs to test that my form is sending the right data, but Orbeon Forms doesn't support writing to disk with a `file:///` URL in submission. What other, more portable alternative could I use?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to test submission with replace instance, the similar echoinstance service will respond with the request entity, and the same Content-Type:

```
<xforms:submission id="echo-submission" method="post"
    resource="http://xformstest.org/cgi-bin/echoinstance.sh"
    ref="instance('data')" replace="instance"/>
```

Please note that bandwidth on xformstest.org is limited, so if you need to make the echo or echoinstance service part if your integration test infrastructure for continuous use, ask for help in setting up your own copy of the service.

Answer (score 0):

**Using the XForms test suite echo service**

You can use the echo service also used by the [XForms test suite](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/Forms/Test/). That echo service returns an HTML page with information about what you submitted, which is a good way for you to check that you are submitting the correct data. Your submission will look at follows, and also see this [full example using the XForms test suite echo service](https://gist.github.com/1254785).

```
<xforms:submission id="echo-submission" method="post"
    resource="http://xformstest.org/cgi-bin/echo.sh"
    ref="instance('data')" replace="all"/>
```

**Using the jsFiddle echo service**

You can use the [jsFiddle echo service for XML](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html#xml), which allows you to do a `replace="instance"`. The jsFiddle echo service doesn't take the XML in the body of the POST, but as an `xml` form-encoded parameter in the POST. So you need to first encode the XML you want to post, as done in the submission below, and also in this [full example using the jsFiddle echo service](https://gist.github.com/1254839).

```
<xforms:submission id="echo-submission" method="post"
        resource="http://jsfiddle.net/echo/xml/"
        serialization="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        ref="instance('jsfiddle-out')" replace="instance" instance="jsfiddle-in">
    <xforms:setvalue ev:event="xforms-submit" ref="instance('jsfiddle-out')"
                     value="saxon:serialize(instance('data'), 'xml')"/>
</xforms:submission>
```